# How to manually install Zurb Foundation?

Tags: css, installation, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to follow the Zurb Foundation "manually installation".

According to the [instructions](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html#nocli):

> First you will need to clone or download the [master zip of the
>   Foundation Compass Template from Github](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html#nocli). This will be the root of
>   your project.
>
> Then you will create a directory called bower_components.
>
> The next step is to clone or download the master zip of the
>   [bower-foundation](https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation) repo in that directory.
>
> Then rename this directory to "foundation".

And then [it says](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass-files.html#filelist) that the filelist should be like this after following all the instructions:

```
  bower_components (folder)
  js  (folder)
     app.js
  scss  (folder)
     _settings.scss
     app.scss
  stylesheets  (folder)
     app.css
     bower.json
     config.rb
     humans.txt
     index.html
     robots.txt
```

Now, I'm probably missing something really silly here, **but there's no way that following those instructions I get that file structure.**

For a starter, there's no .rb file, and `bower-foundation` has a `foundation` and `vendor` folders inside the `js` folder! And how about the `spec` folder that's inside the foundation-master zip file? And you get more than one scss folder.

So, maybe I'm somewhat burnout and don't quite understand the instructions properly?

Comment: Yea, these instructions look like they are a little bit outdated. Do you still need some help with installing Foundation?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I think I still needed it. I mean I think I should get all the files from the first github master zip *only* and add its contents into my root project folder. Is that correct?

Comment: Never mind, I've tried the CLI installation and it works like a charm. But I still think that they should update the manual installation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone out there happens to bump into the same issue, I've solved it following their [video instructions](http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/video-started-with-foundation.html) to do it **with the CLI** (using the command line).

After doing it (it's pretty fast and straightforward), I can confirm that **their "manual instructions" are NOT correct, so please, up until they update them you should NOT use those instructions.**